# Displaying code in a textbox

Tags: c#

What I want to do is display a messagebox(which is working) and take the `MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text)` code and put it into a richtextbox when the button is clicked. I am getting an error though, Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string' Any idea how I can do this?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    yo();
    richTextBox1.Text = yo();
}
void yo()
{ 
    MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text); 
}
```

Comment: +1 for your method name. Yo();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `void` method does not return a value. Consider changing your method to return a string:

```
string yo()
{ 
    MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
    return  textBox1.Text + " " + textBox2.Text;
}
```

Edit based on your comment:

Using [composite formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
return string.Format("MessageBox.Show(\"{0}\", \"{1}\");", textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
```

Answer (score 4):

`yo()` returns `void`, not a `string`. First you call `yo()`, then you set `richTextBox1.Text` to the value returned by `yo()` which is why the compiler is complaining.

You need to either change the return value of `yo()` to a `string`, then return a `string` from it, or write another method altogether that creates the `string` that you want to set to `richTextBox1.Text`.

Answer (score 0):

`void`  method doesn't return a value.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong.

You want to display the string "MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text)" in your rich text box? 
If so the following would suffice

```
string yo()
{  
    return  "MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text)";
}
```

Comment: He wants to "display a messagebox", not to display a "MessageBox.Show..." string.

Comment: tbh, I like the approach.

Comment: @Johnny maybe you were too quick to judge, the answer provided seems to have the same result as what I suggested.